# How to add Total Row in Order Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

I have installed magento 1.9.2.3 version.

My client requirements is to take the Order Amount total in a Day.

Let say he want to know how many order comes in a day and what is the Order Amount.

Can anybody let me know how can we do this because i am new in magento?

thanks

Comment: Hello Muneeb Ahmad, this questions appears to be too broad. What have you tried? Do you have some code to share with us ?

Answer (score 0):

In default magento this type functionality available in admin end

Go admin side top menu `Reports -> Sales -> Orders`